# Unable to download files (18.04)

Tags: steam, downloads

so I recently got Wifi on my Linux, so I went to go download some programs such as Discord and Steam. They both successfully download from my browser, however when I get to install them via `Ubuntu Software`, I click install, it asks my for my password and I enter it correctly, but the progress bar goes away and it doesn't download. Does anybody know why this is happening or how I can fix it? Also, the file types are `.deb`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T), `cd` to your Downloads folder, and enter `sudo dpkg -i filename.deb` . This will give you a more informative error message.

Comment: That worked, it says `dpkg: error processing package steam-launcher (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 steam-launcher
`

Comment: Oh also, when I try to run an `.exe` in `Ubuntu Software` it has a message at the top saying `Don't know how to handle ...`.

Comment: This is (probably) a summary of error messages that came before these. You need to install other packages first, but we don't know which packages. You could try to install pending dependencies with `sudo apt -f install` .

Comment: There is no concept of ".exe" programs in Linux. Files are not executable because they have a ".exe" suffix. You are probably trying to execute a Windows program.

Comment: Oh okay, I found out what packages I need, it says `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of steam-launcher:
 steam-launcher depends on python; however:
  Package python is not installed.
 steam-launcher depends on curl; however:
  Package curl is not installed.
 steam-launcher depends on python-apt; however:
  Package python-apt is not installed.
`

Comment: Can't you just do `sudo apt install steam`?

Comment: When I do it just says it has not installation candidate.

Comment: Whenever I do something it says I'm missing Python, curl, and Python-apt.

Comment: When I try to run Steam from desktop it says 'You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libc.so.6'